# jquery init multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

In the following code I'm trying to initialize two tab-control (`actions-power` and `actions-access`) but initialization occurs only for the first tab control, not both. How i cat fix it?

```
<div id="action-tabs">
        <ul class="tabs" id="actions-power">
            <li class="active"><a href="#action-power_cycle" data-toggle="tab">Power Cycle</a></li>
            <li><a href="#action-power_off" data-toggle="tab">Power Off</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="tabs" id="actions-access">
            <li class="active"><a href="#action-console" data-toggle="tab">Console Access</a></li>
            <li><a href="#action-reset_root_password" data-toggle="tab">Reset Root Password</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-contents">
           <div id="action-power_off">
                <p>This will power off your pc.</p>
                <p>...</p>
           </div>
           <div class="" id="action-power_cycle">
                <p>This will reboot your pc.</p>
                <p>...</p>
           </div>
           <div id="action-console">
                <p>...</p>
           </div>
           <div id="action-reset_root_password">
                <p>...</p>
          </div>
</div> 

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#action-tabs").tabs();
        });
</script>
```

Comment: keeping all li elements in the same ul list http://jsfiddle.net/peTLa/  like this would work, why do you need two separate ul lists?

Comment: @Ekim these tabs nested within another control there and I need to hide part of the tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, selecting an id will only select the first item it encounters. You will need to find another way to select an object if you want to select multiple at a time. For example, try giving each element a class and select that class instead of the id.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/peTLa/1/

instead of grouping the other tabs in a list, we can add a class name to the LI's then we can hide and show the elements with that class only

```
<li class="active other-tabs"><a href="#action-console" data-toggle="tab">Console Access</a></li>
<li class=" other-tabs"><a href="#action-reset_root_password" data-toggle="tab">Reset Root Password</a></li>


$(".other-tabs").hide();
```

I also added a code to select the first tab when you hide them, so if the 3rd or 4th tab is active when hidden the content will not remain for that tab.

```
$("#action-tabs").tabs('select', 0);
```